# Get rows with certain ID from all CSV files in one directory and create a new CSV file containing records only with that ID

Tags: python, pandas, csv, directory

I'm new to python and looking for help.

I have multiple files in one directory from which I need to pull rows with certain ID and save those into a new CSV file. My directory looks like this:

```
2019-09-01.csv
2019-09-02.csv
2019-09-03.csv
2019-09-04.csv
2019-09-05.csv
2019-09-06.csv
...
```

My file structure:

```
   date        id     itemName   customerCount  orderCount
2019-09-01    1234     Guitar         72            90
2019-09-01    5432     Drums          15            15
...
```

Would someone be able to give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can you be more specific? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

To get all your csv files, we can use OS module like below:

```
import os

all_files = []

for dirpath, dirname, files in os.walk('<your path where csv files are located>'):
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        all_files.append(file)
```

This will list all of your CSV files.

Now to read the CSV file, filter based on the ID and write to another csv file, you can use something like the below shown:

```
import pandas as pd
df01 = pd.read_csv('2019-01-01.csv')
df02 = pd.read_csv('2019-01-02.csv')

id01 = [1234,5432]

df01_filt = df01[df01['id'].isin(id01)]

df02_filt = df02[df02['id'].isin(['4023'])]

df_final = pd.concat([df01_filt, df02_filt])
df_final.to_csv('output.csv')
```